# What is the name for "for $x in ... return ..." syntax in XPath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have this xpath:

```
/document/offers/offer/concat(price/text(), for $r in . return 'default-value'[not($r/price/text())])
```

which solves my problem (default value for missing tags) for this document:

```
<document>
  <company>
    <ceo>Elon Musk</ceo>
    <employees>13058</employees>
    <address>
      <city>Palo Alto</city>
      <state>California</state>
      <country>USA</country>
    </address>
  </company>
  <offers>
    <offer avail="0">
      <id>1</id>
      <model>Tesla Roadster</model>
      <imageUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/sites/default/files/styles/blog-picture_2x_1400xvar_/public/0H8E6227_1.jpg</imageUrl>
    </offer>
    <offer avail="1">
      <id>2</id>
      <model>Tesla Model S</model>
      <price>63400.00</price>
      <offerUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/models</offerUrl>
      <imageUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/tesla_theme/assets/img/models/section-initial.jpg</imageUrl>
    </offer>
    <offer avail="1">
      <id>3</id>
      <model>Tesla Model X</model>
      <price>69300.00</price>
      <offerUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/modelx</offerUrl>
      <imageUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/tesla_theme/assets/img/modelx/section-exterior-profile.jpg</imageUrl>
    </offer>
    <offer avail="1">
      <id>4</id>
      <model>Tesla Model 3</model>
      <price>35000.00</price>
      <offerUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/model3</offerUrl>
      <imageUrl>https://www.teslamotors.com/sites/default/files/images/model-3/gallery/gallery-1.jpg</imageUrl>
    </offer>
  </offers>
</document>
```

by returning:

```
default-value
63400.00
69300.00
35000.00
```

According to http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi, this works but I cannot make this work with lxml in python. Right now I don't know even how to google equivalent of this type of xpath. So... how those "inner fors" are called in xpaths?

Comment: lxml uses libxml, which only implements XPath 1.0, hence your issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an [xpath2 for-expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions) which is not supported by lxml or xml.etree in python. You could replicate it using a for loop

```
from lxml import  etree

xml = etree.parse("the_file")
for node in xml.xpath("//document/offers/offer"):
    pr = node.xpath("./price")
    print(pr[0].text if pr else "Default-value")
```

Which would give you:

```
Default-value
63400.00
69300.00
35000.00
```

Comment: the whole point of this, was to avoid `n+1` queries for `n` nodes, which is soo slow :( But thanks.

Comment: @noisy, ...the second query is only searching a subtree. That's waaay faster than the whole document. And, well, this *did* answer your question. If what you really wanted to know was how to do this in a performant way in XPath 1.0, you should have asked that instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: correct. Answer is already accepted. I need to make some tests. I have more than 500 000 nodes, so even if those subqueries are much faster still they have to be 500 000 of them instead of one.

Comment: Sure. If performance is your first goal, maybe Python and XPath isn't the right stack to use for the job. I've seen some folks reporting hugely impressive performance numbers from combining clojure.data.xml/parse and specter -- but even without going that far, any decent XQuery datastore would give you both your single-invocation syntax *and* a proper query optimizer and database index.

Comment: If you care about performance, BTW, is there a reason you're doing `.//price` instead of `./price`? No point to making a search recursive when it doesn't need to be. (This is one of the things a good XQuery optimizer can fix, by the way -- checking the structural index can validate that `price` is only ever directly under `offer`, and thus that it doesn't *need* to be recursive). Same for `//document`, for that matter, unless you actually have multiple documents inside `the_file` -- but even then it's more efficient to give a direct path rather than doing an unbounded recursive search.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, nope, the `//` was meant to be just a single `/`.

Comment: Oh -- I'd actually missed that that was your change, rather than something from the OP's code.